# How to bring a recordset into a table in Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access, adodb, recordset

I am trying to write a VBA code to query from an SQL database, and append the values into an Access table.

I could only write a query and create a connection to the server.

How do I bring it into the Access table?

```vb
Sub getInv()

Dim RowCount As Long, ColCount As Long
Dim cnn As Object
Dim RS As Object
   
Set cnn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set RS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Dim SQLQuery As String

SQLQuery = _
  "SELECT " & _
  "PSDDD.SDDPP, PSDDD.SPPRD " & _
  "WHERE " & _
  "PSDDD.SDDPP = '2244556'" & _
  "ORDER BY " & _
  "PSDDD.SDDPP ASC, PSDDD.SPPRD DESC "

ConnectString = _
  "DRIVER={Client Access ODBC Driver (32-bit)};" & _
  "UID=abbsx;PWD=password;" & _
  "SYSTEM=ABCSQT;DBQ=SSTNCHP22DB;"

cnn.Open (ConnectString)

RS.Open SQLQuery, cnn

' I believe i should put the code for writing into access table here.

'Close the Recordset and Connection
RS.Close
cnn.Close

Set RS = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing

Exit Sub
```

Comment: Are you missing a FROM in the sql?  Are you running this code from Access?  You dont need to connect to your DB, you ned to connect to the SQL database, do you mean a SQL server, or do you want to add the results from a query to a table.

Comment: I actually copied this code from one of my earlier Excel VBA codes. It works in Excel. I intentionally removed FROM from statement to simplify the look in Stackoverflow. It stays in original string. My goal is to bring this data from SQL database (From an ERP system) into a table in Access

Comment: You could just link to the table from access linked table manager and then use a simple INSERT INTO from SELECT on this table?

Comment: I will only bring some values with WHERE statement. I actually don't wanna link the tables i only ant to read from it. And in the Access table where i will keep these records will have other data sources as well. I will add manual data and add custom columns too. But if you think your offer can solve my problem, i would try it. How should I do it? Do you know any tutorial for this purpose?

Comment: If you don't want to set a table link, loop through recordset and save each record to Access table with `CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO... VALUES(concatentate references to recordset fields)"`. Setting a table link seems easier and more efficient.

Comment: I have 1 Question, if i link the tables, when I change something on the linked table in access, would it change the original table in the ERP system? I don't want that, and that's my concern why I insist on loop solution. If there is a way to link these tables but it will only be read only from the source, i'll definitely use this option.

Answer (score 0):

erden. I hope this code gives you inspiration to solve your problem.

```
Public Function appendSelectedStudentsIntoPoolTable(Interest As String) As Long

    Dim rSQL As String, rParams As String
    Dim aSQL As String, aParams As String
    Dim sourceTable As String, targetTable As String
    
    sourceTable = "tStudents"
    targetTable = "tStudentsPool"
    'Note for targetTable: ID column not set to autonumber because to preserve
    'original data as in the source table. But you can use it as PK as long no
    'duplication on IDs.
    
    rParams = "PARAMETERS [par_interest] Text(50); "
    rSQL = rParams & "SELECT ID, Email, FirstName " & _
            "FROM " & sourceTable & _
            " WHERE Interest = par_interest;"
            
    aParams = "PARAMETERS [par_ID] Long, [par_Email] Text(255), " & _
              "[par_FirstName] Text(50); "
    aSQL = aParams & "INSERT INTO " & targetTable & _
            " (ID, Email, FirstName) " & _
            "VALUES (par_ID, par_Email, par_FirstName);"
    
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rQDf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim aQdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rec As Variant
    Dim rsCount As Long 'change data type as needed
    Dim appendedCount As Long 'same as rsCount data type
    Dim i As Long 'same as rsCount data type
    
    'On Error GoTo commit_failed
    
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rQDf = db.CreateQueryDef("", rSQL)
    rQDf.Parameters("par_interest") = Interest
    
    Set rs = rQDf.OpenRecordset()
    With rs
    On Error Resume Next: .MoveLast
    On Error Resume Next: .MoveFirst
    
    If .RecordCount > 0 Then
        Do While Not rs.EOF
            Set aQdf = db.CreateQueryDef("", aSQL)
            aQdf.Parameters("par_ID") = !ID
            'add routine(s) to check existing ID on pool table here
            'before record append to pool table
            'to prevent duplicate ID. For now, i skip it.
            aQdf.Parameters("par_Email") = !Email
            aQdf.Parameters("par_FirstName") = !FirstName
            aQdf.Execute dbFailOnError
            aQdf.Close
            appendedCount = appendedCount + 1
            .MoveNext
        Loop
        
    .Close
    rQDf.Close
    End If
    End With
    
    appendSelectedStudentsIntoPoolTable = appendedCount: Exit Function
        
commit_failed:
    appendSelectedStudentsIntoPoolTable = 0
    'You can put error handler here
    
End Function
```